# Function conflict between __get__ and __getattribute__

Tags: python, get, descriptor, getattribute

I'm writing some code in python 3.9 and have just recently discovered about descriptors.

I have created a class which looks like this:

```py
import threading

class OuterClass():
    class DecoratorTest():
        def __init__(self,fget,fset=None) -> None:
            self.fget=fget
            self.fset=fset
            self.event=threading.Event()
        def __getattribute__(self, name: str):
            return object.__getattribute__(self,name)
        def __get__(self,obj,objtype=None):
            return self.fget(obj)
        def __set__(self,obj,value):
            self.fset(obj,value)
            self.event.set()
            self.event.clear()
         def setter(self,fset):
            return type(self)(self.fget,fset)
      
    def __init__(self):
        self.random_value=10
    @DecoratorTest
    def test_property(self):
        return self.random_value*2
    @test_property.setter
    def test_property(self,value):
        self.random_value=value
```

My intent is to have a decorator which adds an event to the decorated property, so that when the property is changed, the event is set. This is an example of how I would use it:

```py
class_iteration=OuterClass()

def test_funct():
    while True:
        class_iteration.test_property.event.wait()
        print("Changed!")

threading.Thread(target=test_funct).start()

class_iteration.test_property=100
```

Problem is that when I try to get event, it considers `class_iteration.test_property` to be an int object, thus it throws an error. I wonder if there is any way to bypass the `__get__` when using `__getattribute__`, so that I can access the `event` variable, or if I need to change my approach completely.

Comment: Do you need getter at all? Or can it be accessed with e.g. `instance.test_property.get`?

Comment: You can retrieve property from `__dict__` of class: `OuterClass.__dict__['test_property'].event`. Warning: in your example `Event` will be shared among all `OuterClass` instances, because `DecoratorTest.__init__` is called when `OuterClass` is defined, not when it's instantiated. That's why `test_property` is in `OuterClass.__dict__`, not in `class_iteration.__dict__`. You can add debug `print()` to `DecoratorTest.__init__` to make sure (should print twice, because `setter` creates new class which is instantiated then).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to two things. One has to do with the implementation of the `__get__()` method in your descriptor class' implementation. It doesn't check for its *`obj`* argument being `None` like the one as shown in the [pure Python `Property` class](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) described in the documentation.

This is important because it will allow you to fix the second problem, which is with how the `test_funct()` thread accesses the `test_property` — it needs to do so through the class not the instance. 
So, instead of:

```
class_iteration.test_property.event.wait()
```

it should use:

```
type(class_iteration).test_property.event.wait()
```

(Note in the code below I've changed the name of this variable from `class_iteration` to `class_instance` to better reflect what it actually is.)

This is because the `threading.Event` instance is shared by all instances of the `OuterClass` since the `DecoratorTest` class instance is created when its class definition is executed.

Below is your code with those fixes (and some others I made to extend the testinga little and to prevent it from hanging when it ends). I've also reformatted it to adhere to the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines for improved readability.

```
import threading
import time


class OuterClass:
    class DecoratorTest:
        def __init__(self, fget, fset=None) -> None:
            self.fget = fget
            self.fset = fset
            self.event = threading.Event()

        def __getattribute__(self, name: str):
            return object.__getattribute__(self,name)

        def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
            if obj is None:  # Called for decorator instance?
                return self
            if self.fget is None:
                raise AttributeError(f'unreadable attribute {self._name}')
            return self.fget(obj)

        def __set__(self, obj, value):
            self.fset(obj, value)
            self.event.set()
            self.event.clear()

        def setter(self, fset):
            return type(self)(self.fget, fset)

    def __init__(self):
        self.random_value = 10

    @DecoratorTest
    def test_property(self):
        return self.random_value*2

    @test_property.setter
    def test_property(self,value):
        self.random_value = value


class_instance = OuterClass()

def test_funct():
    while True:
        type(class_instance).test_property.event.wait()
        print(f"Change detected: {class_instance.test_property=}")

# Daemon thread so won't prevent termination of main thread if it's running.
threading.Thread(target=test_funct, daemon=True).start()

print(f"Initial value: {class_instance.test_property=}")
time.sleep(.1)
class_instance.test_property = 100
time.sleep(.1)
class_instance.test_property = 200
time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: Does this not answer your question?